# UIPickerView timezone

Tags: ios

How do I set UIPicker timezone?

I have an app that has a dynamic timezone but when I change timezone the pickerview timezone doesn't change and when I select a date the display will have the selected timezone but it displayed different from pickerview.

Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out this code.

```
 [mDatePicker setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
```